# Server Side Blazor UIMouseEventArgs event not working

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a server side Blazor app with latest version but below code which is suppose to toggle text when button is clicked is not working for some reason

```
@page "/Session12/EventHandleDemo"

    <h3>EventHandleDemo</h3>
<button @onclick="@ToggleDisplayText"> Toggle Text </button>

<p>@DisplayText</p>

@code {

    private string DisplayText { get; set; } = "Hello!";

    private void ToggleDisplayText(UIMouseEventArgs args)
    {

        DisplayText = (DisplayText.Equals("Hello!"))
            ? "Hellow world!"
            : "Hello!";

    }
}
```

> It show me error in following line of code `private void
>   ToggleDisplayText(UIMouseEventArgs args)` for `UIMouseEventArgs` and
>   error message is

I have latest version of `dotnet --version` 3.1.100

Update:
My example worked fine when i replaced event `UIMouseEventArgs` with `MouseEventArgs`. I have to check if `MouseEventArgs` is supported in latest version of asp.net blazor or what as i of now i have not found any reason on google or documentation may be its mentioned somewhere i just need to dig deep.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/

Comment: @HenkHolterman, my update to question was based on this link  & other link this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: `UIMouseEventArgs` is not longer supported. All `UI` prefix was removed.

Comment: Well, that documentation is the latest (when you select 3.1 in the topleft). And I pointed to the related release notes.

Answer (score 1):

As "dani herrera" mentioned, use MouseEventArgs. And remove '@' prefixed to method call "ToggleDisplayText".

```
@page "/Session12/EventHandleDemo"

<h3>EventHandleDemo</h3>
<button @onclick="ToggleDisplayText"> Toggle Text </button>

<p>@DisplayText</p>

@code {

private string DisplayText { get; set; } = "Hello!";

private void ToggleDisplayText(MouseEventArgs args)
{

    DisplayText = (DisplayText.Equals("Hello!"))
        ? "Hellow world!"
        : "Hello!";

    }
}
```